# Can't access app code from XCTest

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I have a growing swift project that I have been writing both unit and UI tests for along the way. My UI tests run just fine, but my unit tests have stopped compiling. I am using "@testable import X", but anytime I try to access a class from the project, even if I make that class public, I get a "Use of unresolved identifier" error. I have no idea what I could have changed to cause things to start failing.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Choose "Clean" from the Xcode "Product" menu and then recompile. That will often get it working again. For some reason, we have to "Clean" before the classes are made available to the test target.

My original answer below outlines the old solution before `@testable` was available to us.

--

Make sure the source file for `PostCell` is included in the list of source files for the tests target.

You can do this by going to the tests target and adding it to the list of "Compile Sources":

[image]

Or by clicking on "Target Membership" to the "File Inspector" for the source in question:

[image]

Comment: That would fix the issue, but isn't very clean.